How to deploy my Spring Boot backend to an OVH Cloud VPS server
I have a client that has a website already deployed and working with the database and all in OVH, but all that was done with a previous team, now after updating things inside the database, I want to deploy it and update it in the OVH Cloud VPS server.
To be honest, I never worked with OVH Cloud so it's very confusing, can someone with a previous experience working with it explain the steps on how to update it?
Thank you!

I've just deployed the entire backend and database on a VPS from OVH, since they allow you to set up the environment with Docker, had to make the image from my Springboot server and the compose to arrange the database and the server together.

Firstly, I've acquired the VPS with debian+docker already installed and SSH to manage the server.

Secondly, I've cloned the springboot's git repository to the server.

Thirdly, I've built the springboot image with the Dockerfile (see
this link) and run on the dockerfile's directory (cloned git) with:
docker build -t [image-name] .

Finally, I've created the docker-compose (see this link) to run backend and database
together up (I am not sure if it's necessary on your scenario)
With docker-compose:


docker compose -f local-docker-compose.yml up -d

Without docker-compose:
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 [image-name]

Once your system is up and ready to go, you can try to call at your endpoint with the OVH's VPS IP and open port.
Last but not least, make sure you pass the right information to give access of your database from your backend

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
